# Fragment object is unable to create

Tags: android, fragment

```
Fragment fragment= new BlankFragment();
```

**error :**

```
InCompatiable type
required : android.app.Fragment
Found : com.example.swapnil.Drawer.BlankFragment
```

but I imported

```
android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Wow, please format your question better, and provide the code. If you're using `android.app.Fragment` you must use `android.app.FragmentTransaction` and `getFragmentManager`

Comment: I am using same libs

Answer (score -1):

Try to import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead

Comment: You need to change all your imports that are in relation with Fragment, for example `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: @DavidSeroussi the error explicitly says `required : android.app.Fragment`